# ag grid row data is updating after reset the row data

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to update my row data in ag grid after an edit. But the data is not updated in the grid
I tried with

```
this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
this.rowData = this.countryData;
this.gridApi.refreshCells({ force: true });
```

But none of the options are working here.

Here is my stackblitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-uh7vqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Please help me that what is way to reset the data in ag gird
After clicking the reset button i like to refresh the agrid with old value
i.e the edited value shoudld be replaced by original value

The red marked value should be replaced by old value

[image]

Comment: countryData and rowData are same? What are you trying to refresh?

Comment: @DeepakJha After pressing reset button i like to refresh the grid with old value. Attached the screen shot above

Comment: @RajeshKumar, check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowData` and `countryData` are assigned with the same dataset.

So, when you are changing grid value `countryData` is also being modified.

So, you need to deep copy your raw data when you are populating `countryData` for the first time. And when trying to reset, populate `rowData` from deep copied data from `countryData`. So that, you can there are no reference between `rowData` and `countryData`.

A way to deep copy is to stringify and parse the same data. Like:

```
this.countryData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**Working demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-qr5cfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-yr6yth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I think I got your problem, this is due to the object deep copy. When you receive data you are essentially copying the same object twice and when reference of both the object remain same as a result you change one object thinking it will not change other but it changes other as well. You need to create different object for backup data with same value and this should work

```
    this.getCountryList().subscribe(data => {
      this.rowData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      this.countryData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```